# Detecting changes when comparing documents within an index in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I'm using elastic search to store website crawl data in one index. Docs look something like this:

```
{"crawl_id": 1, url": "http://www.example.com", "status": 200}
{"crawl_id": 1, url": "http://www.example.com/test", "status": 200}
{"crawl_id": 2, url": "http://www.example.com", "status": 200}
{"crawl_id": 2, url": "http://www.example.com/test", "status": 500}
```

How would I compare 2 different crawls? For instance
I want to know which pages have changed their status code from 200 to 500, in crawl_id 2 when I compare crawl_id 2 with crawl_id 1.

I'd like to get the list of documents, but also aggregate on those results.
For instance 1 page changed from 200 to 500.

Any ideas?

Comment: You aggregate "url" as "terms" and then a nested "terms" on status".

Answer (score 0):

I would use [parent/child documents](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.x/query-dsl-has-child-query.html) for that. Parents representing each URL, children representing each different crawl event. Then I'd select parents by searching the children (I ignore if this feature is still maintained or if it has changed its name to [join data types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.x/parent-join.html)).

I'd have also have a look to [document versions](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-versioning-support) and see which one fits my requirements better.